# django ajax and non-ajax templates

Tags: django

i have a django template - one that is normally loaded via a standard get request. However, i would also like to use this template for an ajax get.

I know i can use request.is_ajax to distinguish the call, and thus work out *which* page i should serve - what i don't know is how to avoid replication.

The problem is, the page extends a base htm file - one that has all the bells and whistles (you know, header, menu et al). I don't want this to appear in the ajax page though! What i'd like there is for the page to appear, *not* extending base htm

I can only think that perhaps i have two files - one that has just the contents (ajax version) and another that extends base htm, and somehow imports (not extends) the first file...

any ides how i'd do the above, or how i am meant to solve this generally?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In addition to @Daniel response, you can use [yesno](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std%3atemplatefilter-yesno) template filter if you have `request` in context processors, e.g.

```
{% extends request.is_ajax|yesno:"base_ajax.html,base.html" %}
```

This line should be in every template you use for both page and ajax content.

Comment: this is so elegant they're remaking "breakfast at tiffany's" to star it instead of Hepburn

Answer (score 3):

The value of `extends` can be a variable. So you just define a `base_ajax` html which omits the "bells and whistles", and in your view you send either `base` or `base_ajax` to the template context, depending.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 :**

**base.html:**

```
{% block menu %}
menu goes here
{% endblock menu %}
```

**non-ajax.html:**

```
{% extends base.html %}
```

**ajax.html:**

```
{% extends base.html %}

{% block menu %}
{% end block %}
```

**Solution 2:**

use same base.html

**ajax-and-non-ajax.html:**

```
{% extends base.html %}
{% ifequal ajax %}
{% block menu %}
{% end block %}
{% endifequal %}
```